# on click for an anchor enable the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have text field like below which is bydefault disabled.

```
<input disabled="" type="text" name="name" class="inputUsrProfile" placeholder="Add a description about your self..">
```

And the anchor tag is below

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil" id="clickPencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

On the click of the anchor tag I want the textfield to get enabled.

Below is the jquery I am trying which doesn't seem to work.

```
$("#clickPencil").prop('disabled', false);
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/176/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/178/

Comment: [check](http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/178/)

On click I wish to give some border to textfield.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/179/

Comment: It works in the fiddle but doesn't seem to work for me locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the input field not the `i` tag so change the selector to get the input field. Although bind click event using [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method change the property when click event fired.

```
$("#clickPencil").click(function() {
  $(".inputUsrProfile").prop('disabled', false)
});
```

```js
$("#clickPencil").click(function() {
  $(".inputUsrProfile").prop('disabled', false)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input disabled="" type="text" name="name" class="inputUsrProfile" placeholder="Add a description about your self..">
<a id="clickPencil" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"  aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/177/)** try with  click function .and change with `$('input')`

```
 $('#clickPencil').click(function(){
 $("input").prop('disabled', false);
 })
```

Or try with **className**

```
$(".inputUsrProfile").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `click` event of `i`

```
$("#clickPencil").click(function(){
 $("input.inputUsrProfile").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99w1kyp8/3/)

```
$("#clickPencil").click(function() {
   $('.inputUsrProfile').prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });
 });
```

This will work like a `toggle`, check it.